# how to insert the path of my java pocket 

Tags: java, log4j

this is my directory structure:

```
log4j_demo
     --HelloLog4j.java
     --lib
          ---log4j-1.2.8.jar
          ---log4j.properties
```

and when i `javac HelloLog4j.java` show :

```
HelloLog4j.java:2: pocket org.apache.log4j is not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

and i know `org.apache.log4j`  is in the file : `log4j-1.2.8.jar`

so how to insert the path that  make my code show good ,

thanks

Comment: Ummm ... I think you mean "package".  It is a good idea to cut-and-paste error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to add log4j.jar to classpath

```
javac -cp .;lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar HelloLog4j.java
```

The above is for Windows machine. use `:` as classpath separator for Linux/Solaris instead of `;`

see here

- Windows http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html
- Linix/Solaris http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html